# TikZ Draw an arrow with semicircle shaped head

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

How can I draw an arrow with a semicircle head as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: It's in the manual `arrows.meta` library section for version 3 and \above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned  [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse)  in his comment, it is defined in `arrows.meta` library as `Arc Barb[reversed]`. see TikZ and PGF manual, version 3.0.1a, page 204. you can use it as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{Arc Barb[reversed]}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found it after percusse pointed it out and just used it as you suggested.